# Link to Apple Maps with Coordinates and Label

Tags: html, ios, cordova, apple-maps

I'm writing an HTML `<a>` tag to open the native Apple Maps application on iOS from a Cordova app (i.e. a webpage). This is what I have so far:

`<a href="maps:ll=38.897096,-77.036545" class="context-block-button map-button" id="map-button-1"><i class="ss-map icon-left"></i><span>Open in map (maps:)</span></a>`

This works well, and will open the app at the White House in Washington DC. That's the correct place to go. But does anybody know how I can add a label to the map somehow? I tried using `?q=Label` but that just makes the app search after taking me to the specified coordinates.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Using a normal link:**

```html
<a href="
    http://maps.apple.com/?lsp=9902&auid=4158007438164491913&sll=38.897517,-77.036542&q=The%20White%20House&hnear=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW,%20Washington,%20DC%2020500-0003,%20United%20States
">

<span>Open in map (maps:)</span>
  
</a>
```

- With this link you get asked if you would like to open the link in
  **MAPS**.
- ***MAPS*** goes to the coordinates showing the **Label**!
- However, for some reason sometimes it opens *GOOGLE-MAPS* (at the correct coordinates
  though).